# MVVM: binding the View with the ViewModel with closures, how that results in retain cycle?

Tags: swift, mvvm, closures, weak-references

I'm implementing a simple ItemListing app where the ProductList viewController manages a table view which shows the results of a call to a REST service. The Detail viewController manages a view where I show more information about the item selected in the ProductListVC. I'm trying to apply MVVM pattern. I am using closures for the binding between view model and View controller. In the ProductList viewController, I create and initialize its viewModel this way:

```swift
class ProductListVC: UIViewController {
    var viewModel: ProductViewModel = ProductViewModel()
    var productTblView = UITableView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        initViewModel()
    }
    
    func initViewModel() {
        viewModel.reloadTableViewClosure = { [weak self] () in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.productTblView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    
        viewModel.fetchData()
    }
}
```

My question is what is the need of using `[weak self]` in `reloadTableViewClosure`? How the strong reference happens in this case? It would be great if anybody can explain the usage of `[weak self]` or `[unowned self]` in this case. My confusion is, since the `reloadTableViewClosure` is owned by viewmodel how self maintains strong reference to closure?

Answer (score 1):

Unowned reference can’t be nil and Weak can. see the reference
https://medium.com/@kiran.jasvanee/difference-between-unowned-self-and-weak-self-in-swift-310c14961953

https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/weak-self/

Answer (score 0):

Here [weak self] used for your productTblView, not for viewModel. "self" is specifying here for ProductListVC.
Suppose the controller object has been deallocated and then we update strongly productTblView. It will cause a crash so we use [weak self]/[unowned self].

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It would be great if you can explain some more details. How the strong reference cycle happens if I didn't add [weak self] or [unowned self].I am a beginner in iOS programming, trying to understand concepts clearly. Thank you in advance

Comment: When you will do not use weak and unowned then it makes a strong reference. To avoiding strong references we need to use weak and unowned. Whenever we use objects inside dispatch block directly called with self there it makes a strong reference.